# Pydantic accept integer as string input

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

For a FastAPI Pydantic interface I want to be as tolerable as possible, such as receiving an integer for a string parameter and parse that integer to string:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class FooBar(BaseModel):
    whatever: str
    
FooBar(whatever=12)
```

Gives:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for FooBar
whatever
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=12, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/string_type
```

I think in earlier versions this was possible.

- Python 3.10
- pydantic==2.4.2
- pydantic_core==2.10.1

Comment: before it was possible to do that. but apparently, with the newer version of `pydantic` you need something extra which is mentioned in given answer to this question by M.O.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality was just reintroduced in version 2.4.0. You need to add the [`coerce_numbers_to_str` configuration](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.coerce_numbers_to_str):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class FooBar(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(coerce_numbers_to_str=True)

    whatever: str
```